# Angular unit test case keyboard event is not working

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine

I have one unit test case for the keyboard enter key event on text-area, but its not working.

code.spec.ts

```
textArea.value = "abcd`~";
```

---

```
 const event = new KeyboardEvent("keypress",{
  "key": "Enter"
  });
  textArea.dispatchEvent(event);
```

but i tried another way to trigger the text-area event but its working,

```
textArea.dispatchEvent(new Event('input')); // I can trigger the event
 fixture.detectChanges();
```

---

Please suggest what is the difference between the two event.

Comment: Make sure the event you trigger is exact the same as in the hmtl.
A `keyup.enter` is not the same as `keypress.enter`, if the event is not there it can't be triggered. Also if the event if behind an `*ngIf` you need to check the value and `fixture.detectChanges();` first.